# how to populate doc file on view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

i store doc file into sql server data  base i want view this file on my view page how i can view this file on view plz any one help me 
my class code is here

```
 public  class Candidate : System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo
{

  [Column]
  public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Filecontent { get; set; } 

  }
```

my controllercode is here;

```
       public ActionResult CreateCandidate(Candidate candidate, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    { 

         candidate.Filecontent = Request.Files["file"].ContentType;
                        Stream filestream = Request.Files["file"].InputStream;
                        int filelength = Request.Files["file"].ContentLength;
                        candidate.FileData = new byte[filelength];
                        filestream.Read(candidate.FileData, 0, filelength);
                        IcandidateRepository.SaveCandidate(candidate);
                        return RedirectToAction("CandidateDetails", new { id = 
      candidate.CandidateID });

      }
```

i store this file in binary format plz give me sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a controller action which would allow users to download this file:

```
public ActionResult Download(int? id)
{
    byte[] doc = FetchDocumentFromDatabase(id);
    if (doc == null) 
    {
        // no document found with the given id
        throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
    }
    return File(doc, "application/msword", "document.doc");
}
```

Now, what is left is to provide your users with a link on the view so that they can download it:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("download document", "download", new { id = "123" }) %>
```

Comment: hi Darin i didn't want download user click on the link and  view this file not download

Comment: @sandy, view the file where? It's Word doc file. Are you asking about converting a doc file into HTML?

Comment: without converting is not possible to view

Comment: @sandy, of course that it is not possible. No browser is capable of understanding and display Word Doc files.

Comment: then how to convert in html and display on aspx page

Comment: you have any idea how to convert and display file on view

Comment: @sandy, there is nothing built-in .NET that allows you to do this. You will need a third party library. Most of them are commercial. Google them.

Comment: in job portal site like monster and nukari how to view doc file.

Comment: i convert doc file into html  using word interop  and save into same directory it is converted but i can save this file into another directory it cant convert properly